# Google Universal Analytics: push several sub-events in one impressions event (E-commerce)

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, e-commerce, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I'm trying to implement product impressions (https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#product-impressions) on an ecommerce catalog page using Universal Analytics. The problem i'm having is of practical nature, where I want to push one event containing every impression-object rather than an event for each catalogue product being displayed, but that is not the case as can be seen here:

[image]

Each product being displayed in the catalogue list ends up becoming an impressions-object by itself in the dataLayer, rather than having one impressions-object with all the information (such as Google's own example). Is there a way of nesting each productImpressions event into one, and then pushing that one object containing all catalogue-page results? This is the code I have implemented at the moment which does the pushing to the dataLayer:

```
// Product View, triggered when product is viewed on any page:
function googleTagManagerProductViewDataLayerPush(productName, productSKU, productPrice,
     productBrand, productCategory, productVariant, productList, positionInList, regularProductPrice) {
 dataLayer.push({
     'event': 'productImpressions',
     'ecommerce': {
         'currencyCode': 'SEK',
         'impressions': [{
             'name': productName, 
             'id': productSKU,
             'price': productPrice,
             'brand': productBrand,
             'category': productCategory,
             'variant': productVariant,
             'list': productList,
             'position': positionInList,
             'metric1': regularProductPrice           
         },
         {
             'name': productName, 
             'id': productSKU,
             'price': productPrice,
             'brand': productBrand,
             'category': productCategory,
             'variant': productVariant,
             'list': productList,
             'position': positionInList,
             'metric1': regularProductPrice 
         }]
     }
 });
}
```

I call this function for each product/item on my product catalogue, for instance search results. I'm thinking I could send in arrays but that wouldn't dynamically create objects of each product being displayed nested within one productImpressions event, which I would like.

Does anyone have ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are calling the dataLayer push for every single product. You need to first create an array of all the products and then call dataLayer.push with all of them. Also I'd recommend limiting the number of products you push at once, to maybe 10 or 20 because otherwise the request can get too big and might not be sent.

It also seems like you are pushing the same product twice.

Comment: Looks like I took the example too literal! I failed to see the relation between objects and arrays (and the obvious), but got it right eventually and I am now pushing up all objects in one Impressions array. Thank you, I'm marking this as the correct answer.